# What sentence element does the "In parallel"?

Tags: sentence-structure, parts-of-speech

> The value in this property affects only the operations that the
>   current queue has executing at the same time. Other operation queues
>   can also execute their maximum number of operations in parallel.

What part of speech of **parallel**?

What sentence element does the "In parallel"?
I guess "In parallel" is adverbial.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence "parallel" is a noun.  Look at the m-w.com definition of [parallel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parallel#h2):

"an arrangement or state that permits several operations or tasks to be performed simultaneously rather than consecutively"

Yes, it's adverbial as it describes how the operations are executed.